# are anniversary vs. commemoration equal on sad events - esp pertaining family member's passing

Tags: word-choice

What would be a "better" noun to use in commemoration of a family member's passing - **anniversary**, **commemoration**, **memorial** ? Or are "**anniversary**" and "**commemoration**" 100% exchangeable ?

A similar discussion was posted and answered before -
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145069/is-it-correct-to-use-anniversary-to-commemorate-a-sad-event-or-is-it-better-to

and it partially addressed (a) **anniversary** vs **memorial** and (b) the issue that the noun **anniversary** brings with it a connotation that results from the frequent association of "**anniversary**" to events worthy of "celebration".

In line of the association in (b) for **anniversary**, is **commemoration** a better term, especially for an event to remember a passing family member ? Is "**memorial**" acceptable if the annual memorial event does not take place on the exact day of the member's passing.

Answer (score 2):

Anniversary and commemoration are *not* interchangeable.

An *anniversary* is *the precise date of an event*, happy or sad, eg:

- Today is my wedding anniversary
- Today is the anniversary of my father's death

"Happy" events tend to have their own name, eg "wedding anniversary". You do not normally hear people say "death anniversary", but rather "*the anniversary of [someone's] death*".

A *commemoration* is *the act of remembering an event*, and that does not necessarily occur on the precise date of the anniversary. For example, you may choose to commemorate your wedding anniversary on the nearest convenient weekend if it happened to fall on a weekday one year and it was not convenient to have a party or whatever way you commemorate it, on that date (although you would likely still call the event "an anniversary party").

Similarly, "*Remembrance Sunday*", an event held in the UK to commemorate the lost lives of British and Commonwealth servicemen and women in the two World Wars and later conflicts, is an *annual* event held roughly the same time every year but always on a Sunday, not a specific calendar date. While this event could be called a "commemoration" it is not an "anniversary".

The difference in language between "happy and sad" events is that you are more likely to hear a commemoration called a "*celebration*" if it is a happy event. You would not likely hear someone say "we are celebrating my father's death"; rather "we are memorialising (or remembering) my father's death". However it is increasingly common for a positive outlook to be placed on such events by saying "we are celebrating *the life* of my father on the date of his death".

Although the word "commemoration" itself is not expressly negative, if somebody said "I'm attending a commemoration ceremony" I probably would assume it was a "sad" event, simply because if it was a happy kind of anniversary they'd probably use the name for it (wedding anniversary, birthday etc).

Words like "memorial" tend to be reserved for sombre occasions.